# how to modify a pass-in value as a not nonlocal variable?

Tags: python

I am learning to use a python bytecode preprocessing mechanism.
However it complains when processing these lines of [code](https://github.com/mlcommons/training/blob/master/stable_diffusion/ldm/models/diffusion/ddpm.py#L467-L470):

```
def q_sample(self, x_start, t, noise=None):
        noise = default(noise, lambda: torch.randn_like(x_start))
        return (extract_into_tensor(self.sqrt_alphas_cumprod, t, x_start.shape) * x_start +
                extract_into_tensor(self.sqrt_one_minus_alphas_cumprod, t, x_start.shape) * noise)
```

It said

```
RuntimeError: Preprocessing issues detected:
    Nonlocal variables are not supported but
      q_sample() defined in /opt/dev/training/stable_diffusion/ldm/models/diffusion/ddpm.py:467
      defines nonlocal variable: x_start
```

I don't understand why `x_start` could be nonlocal here. If yes, how can I modify it to be a not Nonlocal variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably the closure created by the lambda. In terms of how to fix this, it would be good to understand more about the python bytecode preprocessing mechanism you mention.

Comment: You can find a good guidance [here](https://python-course.eu/python-tutorial/global-local-variables-namespaces.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is a nested function(the lambda) which has access to a variable(the `x_start`) from the outer function(the `q_sample()`)'s namespace.

To solve that you can make the `x_start` local to the lambda by passing it as the default parameter of the lambda like:

```py
def q_sample(self, x_start, t, noise=None):
    noise = default(noise, lambda x_start=x_start: torch.randn_like(x_start))
```

Here is simplified code for inspection:

```py
def outer(a):
    return lambda: print(a)

closure_function = outer(10)
print(closure_function.__closure__)
print(closure_function.__code__.co_freevars)
```

output:

```
(<cell at 0x102c422c0: int object at 0x10422e718>,)
('a',)
```